# Javascript for loop missing middle part: error or advanced?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am in the process of debugging another developer's Javascript for a project at work.

I am probably a mid-level Javascript developer on a good day and I've come across a for loop that appears broken:

```
for(i = 0; ; i++)
```

Can anyone tell me if this is indeed a mistake or if in some instances this is a perfectly valid way to do Advanced things?

Comment: By advanced I mean encapsulation, recursion, closures, etc. Things I don't fully understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's OK and perfectly legal.  Any of the three slots in a `for` statement can be left empty.  Except for the condition that i added, it's logically the same as this:

```
i = 0;
while (true) {
    // other code here
    if (some condition) {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

It will be an infinite loop unless there is a test somewhere in the loop that issues a `break` statement under some conditions to stop the loop (I added a sample test to my code example).

Comment: That makes sense, if still a bit confusing. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Also, (I'm probably being nit-picky, but since you made an edit to you post indicating that the only difference is the if statement you added I'll go ahead and) I'll point out that the original code doesn't use the `var` keyword so in the original `i` may be global and here it is local to whatever scope the loop is in. Most likely that is intended anyway though, but if the OP has `var i;` somewhere earlier in the function this is in it would be a redundant variable declaration to repeat it.

Comment: @ascii-lime - OK, I took out the `var`.

Answer (score 3):

That is valid. Each of the three expressions in the for loop `for(expr1; expr2; expr3)` can be empty. For example `for( ; ; )` is the same thing as `while(true)`.

`expr1` is an expression that is executed once right before the loop starts. You can also have a variable declaration statement here instead of an expression which is what you have in your code.
`expr2` is an expression that is executed right before every iteration of the loop, and if the value of the expression is falsy the loop is done. If the expression is omitted it is considered truthy.
`expr3` is an expression that is executed right after every iteration of the loop.

The statement you have is essentially a `while(true)` loop (which should contain a `break` statement somewhere within it, that counts the number of times it iterates using the variable `i`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. At my level I'll still stick to basic for loops but it's good to know they are more flexible than I first thought.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly OK so long as inside the loop there's a `break` statement.

If there's no break statement, the JavaScript runtime will continue to execute the code in the loop, over and over again, with "i" growing and growing and growing. Soon, "i" will become a number bigger than anything; bigger than the number of Legos that the rich kid you knew in school had in his playroom even. It'll go right past that to be a number bigger than the number of ants in the world, then the number of Starbucks, then the number of water molecules in the ocean. At some point the browser might ask if you want it to halt the script, but if you're curious, if you're the kind of person who likes to explore the unknown, then you'll decline the offer and let it go. Soon the value of "i" will reach truly astronomical values, and things will become interesting. Remember how in `2001 A Space Odyssey` things got weird when the dude got sucked into Jupiter or whatever? Well it might be like that.

Try a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid approach to do an infinite loop with an incrementing counter. Whether that's intentional or not is a whole other matter, which is why I personally am against using for loops in odd cases like that. Comment would obviously fix any problems with such usage though

Answer (score 0):

A loop has a simple syntax:

1. Variable declaration => i=0
2. Loop enterance check =>
3. Creating another loop => i++

Because JavaScript **returns true for nothing** (correct me if I'm wrong), then **the loop enterance check is always true**.

This is not a good practice at all. Thus I strongly believe that this is a broken code. I haven't seen an example of an infinite loop by design ever.