# how to sort array by last digit?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers

I am required to write a function that receives an array of numbers and
should return the array sorted using for the comparison of their last digit, if their last digit is the same you should check the second to last and so on.

Example:

Input: [1, 10, 20, 33, 13, 60, 92, 100, 21]

Output: [100, 10, 20, 60, 1, 21, 92, 13, 33]

but I get

Output: [ 10, 20, 60, 100, 1, 21, 92, 33, 13 ]

my code:

```js
/**I guess the input numbers are only integers*/
input = [1, 10, 20, 33, 13, 60, 92, 100, 21];

const reverseString = (string) => {
  const stringToArray = string.split("");
  const reversedArray = stringToArray.reverse();
  const reversedString = reversedArray.join("");
  return reversedString;
};

let sortedInput = input.sort((firstNumber, secondNumber) => {
  const firstNumberReversed = reverseString(firstNumber.toString());
  const secondNumberReversed = reverseString(secondNumber.toString());
  const largerOne = Math.max(
    firstNumberReversed,
    secondNumberReversed
  ).toString;

  for (let i = 0; i < largerOne.length; i++) {
    if (firstNumberReversed[i] != secondNumberReversed[i]) {
        if(firstNumberReversed[i] > secondNumberReversed[i]){
            return 1
        }
        if(secondNumberReversed[i] > firstNumberReversed[i]){
            return -1
        }
    }
  }
});

console.log(sortedInput);
```

Comment: `Math.max()` expects numbers, not strings. the content of `largerOne` is the method `.toString`, `largerOne.length` is `1` - always, ...

Comment: If I repalce `const firstNumberReversed = reverseString(firstNumber.toString());
  const secondNumberReversed = reverseString(secondNumber.toString());` with `const firstNumberReversed = parseInt(reverseString(firstNumber.toString()));
  const secondNumberReversed = parseInt(reverseString(secondNumber.toString()));` then I get [ 1, 10, 20, 33, 13, 60, 92, 100, 21 ] as output 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result if you [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it after [reversing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse#:%7E:text=The%20reverse()%20method%20reverses,array%20element%20becomes%20the%20first.) the number

```js
const arr = [1, 10, 20, 33, 13, 60, 92, 100, 21];

const result = arr
  .map((n) => [n, n.toString().split("").reverse().join("")])
  .sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))
  .map((a) => a[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`Remainder Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder):

**Demo:**

```js
const data = [1, 10, 20, 33, 13, 60, 92, 100, 21];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  for (let i = 1, sum = a + b; ; i *= 10) {
    const diff = (a % i) - (b % i);
    if (diff === 0 && i < sum) continue;
    return diff;
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: how for loop work with second part empty? I mean `for (let i = 1; ; i++)`

Comment: The condition defaults to true when empty, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112858/javascript-for-loop-missing-middle-part-error-or-advanced).

Comment: I'd just write `for (let i = 10; ; i *= 10)` and use `i` instead of `10 ** i`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts , I didn't see that, it's way more concise now.